# How to track state change for multiple checkboxes in ko.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, mvvm, knockout.js, observable

Here is the fiddle:https: https://jsfiddle.net/t5v7fmoq/1/

What I want to achieve:

I want to be able to update checkbox view automatically depending on the recieved state variable (which can have true or false value)

state variables (with initial states) for three checkboxes are:

```
  self.state1 = ko.observable(true);
  self.state2 = ko.observable(false);
  self.state3 = ko.observable(true);
```

In the init function I populate observablearray:

```
  self.init = function() {
    self.availableItems([
      new Item(1, "item1", self.state1(), self.onItemStateChange),
      new Item(2, "item2", self.state2(), self.onItemStateChange),
      new Item(3, "item3", self.state3(), self.onItemStateChange)
    ]);
```

In Item function I set the observable properties and onChnage method:

```
function Item(id, name, state, onChange) {
  var self = this;

  self.id = ko.observable(id);
  self.name = ko.observable(name);
  self.state = ko.observable(state);

  self.state.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    onChange(self, newValue);
  });
}
```

With setTimeout I fake an one-time ajax call, which sets new states:

```
setTimeout(()=>{
self.state1(false)
self.state2(true)
self.state3(false)
self.availableItems()[0].state(self.state1())
self.availableItems()[1].state(self.state2())
self.availableItems()[2].state(self.state3())
},1000)
```

But, what I want to achieve, is that I want to avoid typing the following:

```
self.availableItems()[0].state(self.state1())
self.availableItems()[1].state(self.state2())
self.availableItems()[2].state(self.state3())
```

I want to code this behaviour and track this statuses using common practice and optimal coding...
I don't have the idea how to approach this problem differently.

I tried using arrays like this (so that later I can use forach and indexing):

```
setTimeout(()=>{
self.state1(false)
self.state2(true)
self.state3(false)
self.availableItems()[0].state(self.itemStatus()[0])
self.availableItems()[1].state(self.itemStatus()[1])
self.availableItems()[2].state(self.itemStatus()[2])
},1000)
```

But this does not work as expected.

In Short I would like to learn what coding approach to take to code the behaviour, so that when a new state is recieved from server, the proper state is applied to proper checkbox, and proper checkbox view is updated properly.

Comment: Your checkboxes values are displayed based on `Item.state`. Why do you need the `state1`, `state2` and `itemStatus` properties in the `ViewModel`? You could always access them using `availableItems` like how are doing it in `activeItemss`.

Comment: And how is data saved and fetched from server? It's based on `id` field?

Comment: Because with state1, state2 and state3, i am simulating a situation in real code, where I receive data from server, mapped using ko.js mapp plugin

Comment: But, why do you need multiple state properties with consecutive number? The checkbox state is inside `Item` object. Why do you need the duplicate information in `ViewModel`. You'd need to update both places when there's a change. Even if you are getting the data from server, you'd have the `id` parameter to identify which checkbox to update?

Comment: It's because I dont have control over what comes from he servser side. How would I code this in such a case? What do you propose?

Answer (score 1):

General truth: If you create numbered variables (`item1`, `item2`, `item3`), you are doing something wrong. Use arrays.

Depending on *how* you're getting state updates from the server, the implementation of `updateState` needs to be changed. My implementation below assumes you're getting an array of Boolean values, e.g. `[true, true, false]`.

It's a good idea to make viewmodels that accept a `params` object and initialize themselves with it, so that's what the code below does.

```js
function Item(params) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = ko.observable(params.id);
    self.name = ko.observable(params.name);
    self.state = ko.observable(params.state);
}

function ItemList(params) {
    var self = this;

    self.items = ko.observableArray(params.items.map(item => new Item(item)));

    self.updateState = function () {
        var items = self.items(),
            randomStates = items.map(item => Math.random() < 0.5);

        randomStates.forEach((state, i) => items[i].state(state));
    };
}


var viewModel = new ItemList({
    items: [
        {id: "item1", name: "Item 1", state: false},
        {id: "item2", name: "Item 2", state: false},
        {id: "item3", name: "Item 3", state: true},
    ]
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```css
.switchName {
  font-weight: bold;
}
pre {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: smaller;
]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: items">
  <div class="switchBox">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: state, attr: {id: id}">
    <label class="switchName" data-bind="text: name, attr: {for: id}"></label>
  </div>
</div>
<button data-bind="click: updateState">Simulate Random Update</button>

<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this nice explanation. However I cannot mark it as answered, since I still don't know how to approach this problem, because, your assumption was that I get back array from the server, but it is not array, I get back state1, state2 and state3 from the server. Can you please explain how can I modify this code for such case?

Comment: @johndoe *How* are you getting that back? As an object? How does it look like, exactly?

Comment: This is the exact call: 
BaseViewModel.call(this, {
    "state1": 1,
    "state2": 1,
    "state3": 0,
  }, baseEndpoint + '/status');

and in BaseViewModel I have this:
function BaseViewModel(defaults, remoteUrl, mappings) {
  if (mappings === undefined) {
    mappings = {};
  }
  var self = this;
  self.remoteUrl = remoteUrl;

  // Observable properties
  ko.mapping.fromJS(defaults, mappings, self);
  self.fetching = ko.observable(false);
}

Comment: @johndoe Don't post code to the comments. Add it to your question, that's much easier to read.

Comment: @johndoe ...and while you are at it, make a functioning code sample like I did in my answer, complete with Knockout.js and the mapping plugin and the HTML view with your bindings, so that there is a "Run code snippet" button that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Hey, I updated the code in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/81v6knfh/3/
Not sure why some stuff don't work in there, but it's a pretty genuine representation of the situation I have in my real code. Please let me know if there's anything I need to clarify more

Comment: @johndoe Your viewmodel setup does not make a lot of sense. I don't understand the necessity of a `BaseViewModel` (I smell overengineering) and a `StatusViewModel` (What's that even for? All items track their own status.) and I don't get what your `{"state1": "false", "state2": "true", "state3": "false"}` is supposed to do. I get that you want to map `state1` to the first item somehow, but the first item has no relation to that at all (the string "state1" is mentioned nowhere in your items - how is this supposed to work?).

Comment: @johndoe After [cleaning up your code on JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/32sv4crq/18/) from scratch, it looks pretty much like my answer above - only that I'm also using the mapping plugin now. You might want to read the documentation for the mapping plugin again if you're unsure what `ItemList.mapping` does. I assume that you are able to modify what the server sends, and I don't think there is a way around doing this. Sending `{"state1": "false", "state2": "true", "state3": "false"}` makes no sense.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. Apologies for a few mistakes in previous fiddle, Here is the updated one, which will have more sense I believe: https://jsfiddle.net/h6tpofL3/1/

Since this is extremely stripped down version of original code, it is not over-engineered. I don't have control over server side. Only thing I would like to learn is how to code it so that a direct change in self.status.state1 (which is periodically recieved from the server each second) results in that change being applied to proper checkbox....